# Как сделать svg mask для видео?

Tags: html, css, svg, видео, clip-path

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1400 1050" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
  <mask id='mask'> 
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#2A2A2A" /> 
    <path fill="#fff" d="M879.8,797.3c8.29,15.67-4.79,26.09-8.35,31,2.84,10.72-2.08,16.76-8.28,16.77-13,51.09-83.44,38.48-110.48,35.43-74.56,18.58-155,11.27-155,11.27s-3.32,16.5-13.41,24.69c-16.87,33-3.89,69-3.94,107.82,18.93,75.1-39,87.5-39,87.5s-17.76,19.41-33.23,20.25c-8.6.47-119.18,6.66-188.54-44.11-55.34-40.51-73.28-138.21-73.68-151.14-.9-29.15,22.53-34,42.89-72.92s72.51-185,82.05-204c-9.34-3.28-27.12-28-59.53-61.19s-35.21-60.51-44-88.57c5.13-21.94,33.07-6.18,52,3.76,21.58-15.77,67,18.79,67,18.79L435.72,544a179.84,179.84,0,0,0-27.35-27.38c-100.49-38-100.11-77.92-105.66-88-5.11-2.61-20.79-13.85-44-32.21s-90.89-19.19-144.27-22.55c-44.33,7.88-64.81,7.28-83.13,5.91S4.06,397.49.76,390.44c-4.16-19.05,18.39-28.11,18.77-56.36-.1-17.85-13.27-62.61-4.83-69.78,2.86-2.28,29.5,64.94,29.5,64.94s.54,9.92,41.3,1.08C134,314,108,269.13,108,269.13s-.62,1.94-6.43-12.35S78.34,231,57.07,227.8c-20.87-1-47.19-16.64-47.19-16.64l-4.83-6.44,5.9-8.59s18.8,9.47,32.72,9.66,41.17-11.72,58.45-19.32c15.95-13.09,24.29-43,31.11-67.1,18.77-59.68,25.87-65.65,30-70.85s15-23,24.13-24.69c5.72,7.62-13,33.8-20.38,58s3.91,91.62,4.83,98.23,3.93,11.45,18.23,27.37,28.71,7.46,36.47,3.22,8.42-15.94,10.19-19.86,7.24-6.09,13.95-26.84c3.05-23-12.72-45.26-17.17-48.84-67.79-29.53-53.89-53.51-51-54.75s25.31,19.58,37.55,25.23c-7.19-4.28-7.11-11.49-8.05-18.26s6.44-3.75,6.44-3.75,2.59,5.56,8.58,17.71,24.42,14.66,30.57,14.49,18.72-17,26.28-25.76,19.7-38.18,23.6-44.55,6.66-10.13,9.11-17.18c8-8,13.41,2.15,13.41,2.15s2.51-4.68,5.37-9.13c10.13-4.45,8,7,8,7s-30.14,61-34.32,81.59c-1,16.24-8,136.87-8,136.87s-.67,27-3.75,49.39c1.68,14.47,5.8,36.23,30.57,44,25.88,0,34-109.07,39.69-131s16.36-57.61,18.23-66S387,93,392.28,92.53s4.6,12.12,5.36,26.84c2.93,15.41-3,40.6-5.36,47.24-1.2,5.09-6.78,66.15-9.66,85.34-.54,21-9.47,66.23-11.26,78.91s-9.1,62.92-10.73,82.12c13.68,8.7,46.15,16.32,64.9,2.68,15.75-7.8,33.6-57.36,37-66.56s10-33.07,17.16-41.86c10.55,13.55.86,56.32-12.34,88-11.2,26.93-25.11,44.07-29.49,47.77-1.78,11.73,15.6,32,22.52,40.26,8.65-1.05,64.15-40.45,71.33-45.09S540.54,423,543,423.72c7.18,32.08-52,73.53-52,73.53s43.33,14.15,68.11,19.86c25.38-2.17,83.06-24.87,90.65-29s3.88-32,3.21-49.38-9.53-23.56-15-25.77-7.26-8.15.54-7.51c29,.35,34,46,36.47,58,3.16-7,15.17-43.15,15.55-55.29s4.46-9.35,6.44-3.76c11.94,57.19-9.49,84.65-27.35,100.38-15.9,35.5-58.09,49.79-65.43,52.6,9,2.86,46.94,50.29,53.09,57.43,14.78,5.2,74.23,66.8,82.06,73.54S802.66,738.7,816,750.6c13.28,4.88,42.56,29.49,48.27,33.28C870.47,784.85,877.2,793.1,879.8,797.3Z"/>
  </mask>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</defs>

<image width="1400" height="1050" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1835.jpg' mask='url(#mask)' />
</svg>
```

Маска работает на изображение, как сделать, чтобы работала для видео?

Answer (score 3):

Так как `<video>` это тег `HTML5`, поэтому его необходимо вынести за пределы SVG

```html
<video autoplay controls muted src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 882.26px; height: 882px;">
</video>
```

Маску нужно определить в SVG и применить её к  video файлу, который находится вне SVG

```
src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 1920px; height: 1200px; mask: url(#mask)">
```

Чтобы блок SVG не мешал вёрстке, нужно установить его размеры равными нулю

`width="0" height="0"`

**К сожалению маска для видио работает только в Firefox**

```html
<video autoplay controls muted src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 1920px; height: 1200px; mask: url(#mask)">
</video>
<svg width="0" height="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
  <mask id='mask'> 
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#151515" /> 
      <path fill="#fff" d="M879.8,797.3c8.29,15.67-4.79,26.09-8.35,31,2.84,10.72-2.08,16.76-8.28,16.77-13,51.09-83.44,38.48-110.48,35.43-74.56,18.58-155,11.27-155,11.27s-3.32,16.5-13.41,24.69c-16.87,33-3.89,69-3.94,107.82,18.93,75.1-39,87.5-39,87.5s-17.76,19.41-33.23,20.25c-8.6.47-119.18,6.66-188.54-44.11-55.34-40.51-73.28-138.21-73.68-151.14-.9-29.15,22.53-34,42.89-72.92s72.51-185,82.05-204c-9.34-3.28-27.12-28-59.53-61.19s-35.21-60.51-44-88.57c5.13-21.94,33.07-6.18,52,3.76,21.58-15.77,67,18.79,67,18.79L435.72,544a179.84,179.84,0,0,0-27.35-27.38c-100.49-38-100.11-77.92-105.66-88-5.11-2.61-20.79-13.85-44-32.21s-90.89-19.19-144.27-22.55c-44.33,7.88-64.81,7.28-83.13,5.91S4.06,397.49.76,390.44c-4.16-19.05,18.39-28.11,18.77-56.36-.1-17.85-13.27-62.61-4.83-69.78,2.86-2.28,29.5,64.94,29.5,64.94s.54,9.92,41.3,1.08C134,314,108,269.13,108,269.13s-.62,1.94-6.43-12.35S78.34,231,57.07,227.8c-20.87-1-47.19-16.64-47.19-16.64l-4.83-6.44,5.9-8.59s18.8,9.47,32.72,9.66,41.17-11.72,58.45-19.32c15.95-13.09,24.29-43,31.11-67.1,18.77-59.68,25.87-65.65,30-70.85s15-23,24.13-24.69c5.72,7.62-13,33.8-20.38,58s3.91,91.62,4.83,98.23,3.93,11.45,18.23,27.37,28.71,7.46,36.47,3.22,8.42-15.94,10.19-19.86,7.24-6.09,13.95-26.84c3.05-23-12.72-45.26-17.17-48.84-67.79-29.53-53.89-53.51-51-54.75s25.31,19.58,37.55,25.23c-7.19-4.28-7.11-11.49-8.05-18.26s6.44-3.75,6.44-3.75,2.59,5.56,8.58,17.71,24.42,14.66,30.57,14.49,18.72-17,26.28-25.76,19.7-38.18,23.6-44.55,6.66-10.13,9.11-17.18c8-8,13.41,2.15,13.41,2.15s2.51-4.68,5.37-9.13c10.13-4.45,8,7,8,7s-30.14,61-34.32,81.59c-1,16.24-8,136.87-8,136.87s-.67,27-3.75,49.39c1.68,14.47,5.8,36.23,30.57,44,25.88,0,34-109.07,39.69-131s16.36-57.61,18.23-66S387,93,392.28,92.53s4.6,12.12,5.36,26.84c2.93,15.41-3,40.6-5.36,47.24-1.2,5.09-6.78,66.15-9.66,85.34-.54,21-9.47,66.23-11.26,78.91s-9.1,62.92-10.73,82.12c13.68,8.7,46.15,16.32,64.9,2.68,15.75-7.8,33.6-57.36,37-66.56s10-33.07,17.16-41.86c10.55,13.55.86,56.32-12.34,88-11.2,26.93-25.11,44.07-29.49,47.77-1.78,11.73,15.6,32,22.52,40.26,8.65-1.05,64.15-40.45,71.33-45.09S540.54,423,543,423.72c7.18,32.08-52,73.53-52,73.53s43.33,14.15,68.11,19.86c25.38-2.17,83.06-24.87,90.65-29s3.88-32,3.21-49.38-9.53-23.56-15-25.77-7.26-8.15.54-7.51c29,.35,34,46,36.47,58,3.16-7,15.17-43.15,15.55-55.29s4.46-9.35,6.44-3.76c11.94,57.19-9.49,84.65-27.35,100.38-15.9,35.5-58.09,49.79-65.43,52.6,9,2.86,46.94,50.29,53.09,57.43,14.78,5.2,74.23,66.8,82.06,73.54S802.66,738.7,816,750.6c13.28,4.88,42.56,29.49,48.27,33.28C870.47,784.85,877.2,793.1,879.8,797.3Z"/>
  </mask>
 
</defs>
<svg>
```

**Для того, чтобы вырезать видео по требуемой форме и это работало во всех современных браузерах, необходимо применить `clipPath`**

Надеюсь, ответ вам будет полезен.

```html
<video autoplay controls muted src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 1920px; height: 1200px; clip-path: url(#clip)">
</video>

<svg width="0" height="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<defs>
  <clipPath id='clip'>
     
   <path fill="#fff" d="M879.8,797.3c8.29,15.67-4.79,26.09-8.35,31,2.84,10.72-2.08,16.76-8.28,16.77-13,51.09-83.44,38.48-110.48,35.43-74.56,18.58-155,11.27-155,11.27s-3.32,16.5-13.41,24.69c-16.87,33-3.89,69-3.94,107.82,18.93,75.1-39,87.5-39,87.5s-17.76,19.41-33.23,20.25c-8.6.47-119.18,6.66-188.54-44.11-55.34-40.51-73.28-138.21-73.68-151.14-.9-29.15,22.53-34,42.89-72.92s72.51-185,82.05-204c-9.34-3.28-27.12-28-59.53-61.19s-35.21-60.51-44-88.57c5.13-21.94,33.07-6.18,52,3.76,21.58-15.77,67,18.79,67,18.79L435.72,544a179.84,179.84,0,0,0-27.35-27.38c-100.49-38-100.11-77.92-105.66-88-5.11-2.61-20.79-13.85-44-32.21s-90.89-19.19-144.27-22.55c-44.33,7.88-64.81,7.28-83.13,5.91S4.06,397.49.76,390.44c-4.16-19.05,18.39-28.11,18.77-56.36-.1-17.85-13.27-62.61-4.83-69.78,2.86-2.28,29.5,64.94,29.5,64.94s.54,9.92,41.3,1.08C134,314,108,269.13,108,269.13s-.62,1.94-6.43-12.35S78.34,231,57.07,227.8c-20.87-1-47.19-16.64-47.19-16.64l-4.83-6.44,5.9-8.59s18.8,9.47,32.72,9.66,41.17-11.72,58.45-19.32c15.95-13.09,24.29-43,31.11-67.1,18.77-59.68,25.87-65.65,30-70.85s15-23,24.13-24.69c5.72,7.62-13,33.8-20.38,58s3.91,91.62,4.83,98.23,3.93,11.45,18.23,27.37,28.71,7.46,36.47,3.22,8.42-15.94,10.19-19.86,7.24-6.09,13.95-26.84c3.05-23-12.72-45.26-17.17-48.84-67.79-29.53-53.89-53.51-51-54.75s25.31,19.58,37.55,25.23c-7.19-4.28-7.11-11.49-8.05-18.26s6.44-3.75,6.44-3.75,2.59,5.56,8.58,17.71,24.42,14.66,30.57,14.49,18.72-17,26.28-25.76,19.7-38.18,23.6-44.55,6.66-10.13,9.11-17.18c8-8,13.41,2.15,13.41,2.15s2.51-4.68,5.37-9.13c10.13-4.45,8,7,8,7s-30.14,61-34.32,81.59c-1,16.24-8,136.87-8,136.87s-.67,27-3.75,49.39c1.68,14.47,5.8,36.23,30.57,44,25.88,0,34-109.07,39.69-131s16.36-57.61,18.23-66S387,93,392.28,92.53s4.6,12.12,5.36,26.84c2.93,15.41-3,40.6-5.36,47.24-1.2,5.09-6.78,66.15-9.66,85.34-.54,21-9.47,66.23-11.26,78.91s-9.1,62.92-10.73,82.12c13.68,8.7,46.15,16.32,64.9,2.68,15.75-7.8,33.6-57.36,37-66.56s10-33.07,17.16-41.86c10.55,13.55.86,56.32-12.34,88-11.2,26.93-25.11,44.07-29.49,47.77-1.78,11.73,15.6,32,22.52,40.26,8.65-1.05,64.15-40.45,71.33-45.09S540.54,423,543,423.72c7.18,32.08-52,73.53-52,73.53s43.33,14.15,68.11,19.86c25.38-2.17,83.06-24.87,90.65-29s3.88-32,3.21-49.38-9.53-23.56-15-25.77-7.26-8.15.54-7.51c29,.35,34,46,36.47,58,3.16-7,15.17-43.15,15.55-55.29s4.46-9.35,6.44-3.76c11.94,57.19-9.49,84.65-27.35,100.38-15.9,35.5-58.09,49.79-65.43,52.6,9,2.86,46.94,50.29,53.09,57.43,14.78,5.2,74.23,66.8,82.06,73.54S802.66,738.7,816,750.6c13.28,4.88,42.56,29.49,48.27,33.28C870.47,784.85,877.2,793.1,879.8,797.3Z"/>
  </mask>
 
</defs>
<svg>
```